# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'NodeList'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, dragula, angular-dragula

I am using ng2-dragula for Drag and Drop in my Table.

```
  this.dragulaService.drop.subscribe(value => {     

  let questions_group = value[3] as HTMLTableRowElement        
  let SectionTwo:Array<string> = [];
  let QuestionId:Array<string> = [];
  let OrderNo:Array<number> = [];
  var list2 = questions_group.childNodes;      

  list2.forEach( 
    function(currentValue, currentIndex,listObj) { 

      if(currentIndex!=0){           
        let sectionName2 = currentValue.lastChild.textContent
        SectionTwo.push(sectionName2)
        QuestionId.push(currentValue.firstChild.textContent)
        OrderNo.push(currentIndex)

      }         
    },
    ''
  );   });
```

All of sudden it has started giving me error that "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'NodeList'.". Prior it was working fine I didn't do any changes.

Comment: Works fine in the playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20questions_group%20!%3A%20HTMLTableRowElement%0D%0Avar%20list2%20%3D%20questions_group.childNodes%3B%0D%0Alist2.forEach(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20(currentValue%2C%20currentIndex%2C%20listObj)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A)%3B%20%20 What does your tsconfig.json look like ?

Comment: {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it looks like that

Comment: Looks fine a potential source of error would have been of you left out `dom` from the `lib` option but it's not that. It should work ...

Comment: If you jump to the declaration of `childNodes`, what do you see?  It should be `readonly childNodes: NodeListOf<Node & ChildNode>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added property "dom.iterable" in lib in tsconfig.json and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

- Using Spread Operator:

  ```
  var list2 = [...questions_group.childNodes]; // Take a look of the syntax

  list2.forEach(function(currentValue, currentIndex,listObj) => {
     // Todo
  })
  ```